# How to change By class at runtime to generate dynamically changing xpath?

Tags: java, selenium, reflection

In my current framework locators of By class are being changed dynamically say for suppose ok and cancel have same xpath expression except the text Ok and one has text cancel in it then it uses a method called

findElement(driver,generateDynamicPageElements(By b,String s));

where b definition is

By b = By.xpath("//button[text()='{param1}']");

And

s="OK";

Then at runtime it changes the functionality and turns into 
findElement(driver,By.xpath("//button[text()='OK']"));
finds button with text OK how can I achieve it? Since the functionality of generateDynamicPageElement is hidden so I needed to ask this question.

Comment: Consider creating an abstract class for YourSeleniumAction... then extending it for different calls to the driver.  Example is my little hobby project:  https://github.com/pcalkins/browsermator

Comment: Sorry guys I found the solution the By class toString() itself returns the xpath thanks for answering/commenting anyways